# Keep track of pointer to struct i in realloc'ed array of n structs?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I malloc'ed an array of structs. In a loop over pointers to the separate structs then is checked if more structs are needed. If so, a realloc is used to increase the number of structs. However as the realloc might use a different chunk of memory, the old pointer to the last filled structure has to be updated to the new position in memory. What is the best way to keep track at which structure of the array the pointer was pointing last? The code below does not work, it halts with realloc(): invalid old size. I left away the checks for NULL after alloc for clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 2
struct s 
{
  int a;
};
struct s **p;

int main() 
{
    struct s *q;
    int n = N;
    int i, j, m;

    p = malloc(n * sizeof(struct s *));
    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        p[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct s));
    q = p[0];
    for (i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) 
    {
        if ((m = q - p[0] + 1) > n) 
        {
            printf("realloc at n %d\n", n);
            n *= 2;
            p = realloc(p, n * sizeof(struct s *));
            for (j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
                p[j] = realloc(p[j], sizeof(struct s));
            q = p[m - 1];
        }
        q->a = i;
        q++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to be because you don't really understand `realloc()` for example you state that it might give you a different address yet you still doing `p = realloc(p, newsize)`, what if it fails? You will create a memory leak and you will never be able to recover the data `p` pointed to before the call.

Comment: There is no "array of `struct`", but an array of pointers. WHoever told you that is the same should not teach C (or C++), but stick to Java or - better - VBA.

Comment: Yes you're right iharob, should have done that properly. And it's indeed more about realloc.

Answer (score 1):

You allocated an array of pointers. When standard C function realloc is used it copies already existent values in the old array to the new array. There is no need to allocate anew objects pointed to by the elements of the array.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 2

struct s 
{
    int a;
};

int main( void )
{
    struct s **p;
    int n = N;    
    int i, j;

    p = malloc( n * sizeof( struct s* ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) p[i] = malloc( sizeof( struct s ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( i == n )
        {
            struct s **tmp = realloc( p, N * n * sizeof( struct s * ) );

            if ( !tmp ) break;

            p = tmp;
            n = N * n;

            for ( j = i; j < n; j++ ) p[j] = malloc( sizeof( struct s ) ); 
        }

        p[i]->a = i;
    }        

    for ( i = 0; i < ( n < 100 ? n : 100 ); i++ )
    {
        printf( "%2d ", p[i]->a );
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % 10 == 0 ) printf( "\n" );
    }        

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( p[i] );
    free( p );
}
```

Its output is

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Still one more question: why is there no need to check the p[j] for NULL after malloc?

Comment: @J.O.Doe You can add checks everywhere where it is required as for example if ( p[i] ) p[i]->a = i;

Answer (score 0):

The best way to update the pointer to the end of `realloc`-ed block is to not keep that pointer in the first place. Instead of using a pointer, use a numeric offset, and compute the pointer at runtime as needed.

This would help you avoid your first logical problem: writing `q++`, which points past the `malloc`-ed `struct`, when you need to write `q = p[next]`.

Your other problem is when you allocate more data to `p`, doubling `n`:

```
n *= 2;
p = realloc(p, n * sizeof(struct s *));
for (j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
    p[j] = realloc(p[j], sizeof(struct s));
```

Apart from a common problem wit assigning `realloc` result back to `p`, you are `realloc`-ing `struct`-s into the whole array, instead of `malloc`-ing `n/2` elements to the upper part of the array:

```
for (j = n/2 ; j < n ; j++)
    p[j] = malloc(sizeof(struct s));
```

Finally, this expression `q - p[0]` does not make sense: pointers inside `q` and inside `p[0]` do not point to a contiguous region of memory, because each one is allocated separately with `malloc`. Therefore, you cannot apply subtraction to them, and expect the value to represent something meaningful, such as an offset between pointers.